# Reactive mongo group elements and count them

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query, reactivemongo

I have a MongoDB database where are storage different files, those files can be **png**, **jpg**, **pdf**, here an example:

```
{
    "_id" : "id of the document",
    "metadata" : {
        "s" : "documents",
        "u" : "id of the owner",
        "d" : ""
    },
    "filename" : "El-jugador-Fedor-Dostoyevski.pdf",
    "contentType" : "application/pdf",
}
```

I deleted some fields not relevant, the type of the document is given by the `contentType` field, what I want is to get the count of each type of file using Scala and ReactiveMongo

I already did it but doing three consultations, in this way:

```scala
def contentTypeStats(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[ContentTypesDTO] = {
    collectionFactory.collection().flatMap(collection => {

      val filterDocuments = BSONDocument("metadata.s" -> BSONDocument("$ne" -> "thumbnail"))//don't want count thumbnails, only documents
      
      val filterPNG = BSONDocument(filterDocuments, "contentType" -> "image/png")
      val filterJPG = BSONDocument(filterDocuments, "contentType" -> "image/jpeg")
      val filterPDF = BSONDocument(filterDocuments, "contentType" -> "application/pdf")

      val countPNGFuture: Future[Long] = collection.count(Some(filterPNG))
      val countJPGFuture: Future[Long] = collection.count(Some(filterJPG))
      val countPDFFuture: Future[Long] = collection.count(Some(filterPDF))

      for {
        countPNG <- countPNGFuture
        countJPG <- countJPGFuture
        countPDF <- countPDFFuture
      } yield {
        ContentTypesDTO(
          pngCount = countPNG,
          jpgCount = countJPG,
          pdfCount = countPDF
        )
      }

    })
  }
```

I would like to do this with only one consult, in MongoDB I do it this way:

```
db.getCollection('myCollection').aggregate([
    {$match: {'metadata.s': {$ne: 'thumbnail'}}},
    {$group: {_id: "$contentType", count: {$sum: 1}} }
])
```

That return me this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "image/png",
    "count" : 5.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "application/pdf",
    "count" : 9.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "image/jpeg",
    "count" : 8.0
}
```

I try this way:

```scala
def contentTypeStats(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[ContentTypesDTO] = {
    collectionFactory.collection().flatMap(collection => {

      import collection.AggregationFramework._
      val result: Future[Option[BSONDocument]] = collection.aggregatorContext[BSONDocument](
        pipeline = List(
          Match(BSONDocument("metadata.s" -> BSONDocument("$ne" -> "thumbnail"))),
          Group(BSONDocument("_id" -> "$contentType"))("count" -> SumAll)
        )
      ).prepared.cursor.headOption

      result.map {
        case Some(doc) =>
          println(doc.getAsOpt[String]("_id"))//here always return None
          ContentTypesDTO(
            pngCount = doc.getAsOpt[Long]("count").getOrElse(0L),
            jpgCount = doc.getAsOpt[Long]("count").getOrElse(0L),
            pdfCount = doc.getAsOpt[Long]("count").getOrElse(0L)
          )//all have the same number
      }
    })
  }
```

That method return `None` when ask for the `_id` and the count field give randomly some of the previous results (5, 8, 9), it should be a way to access the specific count field of each `_id` that should be either `image/png` or `image/jpeg` or `application/pdf` but how if I can get the `_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of problems in my solution

```scala
val result: Future[Option[BSONDocument]] = collection.aggregatorContext[BSONDocument](
        pipeline = List(
          Match(BSONDocument("metadata.s" -> BSONDocument("$ne" -> "thumbnail"))),
          Group(BSONDocument("_id" -> "$contentType"))("count" -> SumAll)
        )
      ).prepared.cursor.headOption
```

here I was mapping the `_id` as a `BSONDocument`, that's why a could not get that `_id`, so the solution was to mapped as a `BSONString` in this way

```scala
Group(BSONString("$contentType"))("count" -> SumAll)
```

The `Group` method always create the `_id` field with the first parameter.
The second problem was returning the result, here `.prepared.cursor.headOption` only return me the first **BSONDocument** from the created group. To fixed using the Cursor class from reactivemongo
`.prepared.cursor.collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[BSONDocument]]())`
that return me a List of **BSONDocument**
After that also change the `ContentTypesDTO` to just be

```scala
case class ContentTypesDTO(contentType: String,
                           count: Long)
```

And using map on the `result` to get a `Seq[ContentTypesDTO]`
Here the final solution:

```scala
def contentTypeStats(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[ContentTypeDetailsDTO]] = {
    collectionFactory.collection().flatMap(collection => {

      import collection.AggregationFramework.{Group, Match, SumAll}

      val result: Future[List[BSONDocument]] = collection.aggregatorContext[BSONDocument](
        List(
          Match(BSONDocument("metadata.s" -> BSONDocument("$ne" -> "thumbnail"))),
          Group(BSONString("$contentType"))("count" -> SumAll))
      ).prepared.cursor.collect[List](-1, Cursor.FailOnError[List[BSONDocument]]())

      result.map(docList => {
        docList.map {
          doc =>
            ContentTypeDetailsDTO(
              contentType = doc.getAsOpt[String]("_id").getOrElse(""),
              count = doc.getAsOpt[Long]("count").getOrElse(0L)
            )
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

That method returns this:

```json
[
  {
    "contentType": "application/pdf",
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "contentType": "image/svg",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "contentType": "image/png",
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "contentType": "image/jpeg",
    "count": 8
  }
]
```